# Windows 10 Critical Process Died

Tags: windows-10, bsod

I have Windows 10 Home 64-bit on my desktop. A few weeks ago, I had to reset and reinstall Windows because of a BSOD during an update. Now, I have a new GPU which was installed today. I got a BSOD with stopcode Critical Process Died while the PC was sitting there idle. I analyzed the crashdump file with WinDBG and found the following info:

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

CRITICAL_PROCESS_DIED (ef)
        A critical system process died
Arguments:
Arg1: ffff8d0adf1e2380, Process object or thread object
Arg2: 0000000000000000, If this is 0, a process died. If this is 1, a thread died.
Arg3: 0000000000000000
Arg4: 0000000000000000

Debugging Details:
------------------

ETW minidump data unavailable

KEY_VALUES_STRING: 1


PROCESSES_ANALYSIS: 1

SERVICE_ANALYSIS: 1

STACKHASH_ANALYSIS: 1

TIMELINE_ANALYSIS: 1


DUMP_CLASS: 1

DUMP_QUALIFIER: 400

BUILD_VERSION_STRING:  18362.1.amd64fre.19h1_release.190318-1202

DUMP_TYPE:  2

BUGCHECK_P1: ffff8d0adf1e2380

BUGCHECK_P2: 0

BUGCHECK_P3: 0

BUGCHECK_P4: 0

PROCESS_NAME:  csrss.exe

CRITICAL_PROCESS:  csrss.exe

EXCEPTION_RECORD:  fffff57abd5ea000 -- (.exr 0xfffff57abd5ea000)
ExceptionAddress: 0000000000000000
   ExceptionCode: 20b45867
  ExceptionFlags: 0a000001
NumberParameters: 0

EXCEPTION_CODE: (Win32) 0x20b45867 (548690023) - <Unable to get error code text>

ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0x20b45867 - <Unable to get error code text>

CPU_COUNT: 4

CPU_MHZ: db0

CPU_VENDOR:  GenuineIntel

CPU_FAMILY: 6

CPU_MODEL: 9e

CPU_STEPPING: 9

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN8_DRIVER_FAULT

BUGCHECK_STR:  0xEF

CURRENT_IRQL:  0

EXCEPTION_CODE_STR:  20b45867

ANALYSIS_SESSION_HOST:  DESKTOP-6L7K90U

ANALYSIS_SESSION_TIME:  04-15-2020 20:29:56.0390

ANALYSIS_VERSION: 10.0.18362.1 amd64fre

TRAP_FRAME:  ffff800000000000 -- (.trap 0xffff800000000000)
Unable to read trap frame at ffff8000`00000000

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from fffff8046eacb1e9 to fffff8046e3c1510

STACK_TEXT:  
ffff830f`60d71e18 fffff804`6eacb1e9 : 00000000`000000ef ffff8d0a`df1e2380 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KeBugCheckEx
ffff830f`60d71e20 fffff804`6e9c7893 : ffff8d0a`df1e2380 fffff804`6e29c769 ffff8d0a`df1e2380 fffff804`6e29c8c0 : nt!PspCatchCriticalBreak+0x115
ffff830f`60d71ec0 fffff804`6e83a190 : ffff8d0a`00000000 00000000`00000000 ffff8d0a`df1e2380 ffff8d0a`df1e2380 : nt!PspTerminateAllThreads+0x175cbf
ffff830f`60d71f30 fffff804`6e839f79 : ffffffff`ffffffff ffff830f`60d72060 ffff8d0a`df1e2380 00000000`00000000 : nt!PspTerminateProcess+0xe0
ffff830f`60d71f70 fffff804`6e3d2e15 : 00007ffe`0000029c ffff8d0a`d9dd1080 ffff8d0a`df1e2380 ffff830f`60d721b0 : nt!NtTerminateProcess+0xa9
ffff830f`60d71fe0 fffff804`6e3c5350 : fffff804`6e42ff1e ffff830f`60d72a58 ffff830f`60d72a58 ffff830f`60d721b0 : nt!KiSystemServiceCopyEnd+0x25
ffff830f`60d72178 fffff804`6e42ff1e : ffff830f`60d72a58 ffff830f`60d72a58 ffff830f`60d721b0 00007ffe`3f0fd000 : nt!KiServiceLinkage
ffff830f`60d72180 fffff804`6e3d351d : fffff57a`bd5ea000 ffff830f`60d72b00 ffff8000`00000000 000000f3`bbea0f70 : nt!KiDispatchException+0x168bde
ffff830f`60d72920 fffff804`6e3cf705 : 00000000`0006a1c9 ffff830f`60d72b80 00000000`00000000 ffff8d0a`d46a0380 : nt!KiExceptionDispatch+0x11d
ffff830f`60d72b00 00007ffe`4230a0ae : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiPageFault+0x445
000000f3`bbea0ef0 00000000`00000000 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : 0x00007ffe`4230a0ae


THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD_FUNC:  f6b0f7fafbd5253fc3d42ad0a11af14fddabdcf0

THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD_FUNC_OFFSET:  be9170f6d614d257ce9be03cb2a996eeebc32fc4

THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD:  bc100a5647b828107ac4e18055e00abcbe1ec406

FOLLOWUP_IP: 
nt!PspCatchCriticalBreak+115
fffff804`6eacb1e9 cc              int     3

FAULT_INSTR_CODE:  ed8440cc

SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  1

SYMBOL_NAME:  nt!PspCatchCriticalBreak+115

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: nt

IMAGE_NAME:  ntkrnlmp.exe

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  4269a790

IMAGE_VERSION:  10.0.18362.657

STACK_COMMAND:  .thread ; .cxr ; kb

BUCKET_ID_FUNC_OFFSET:  115

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  0xEF_csrss.exe_BUGCHECK_CRITICAL_PROCESS_d9dd1080_nt!PspCatchCriticalBreak

BUCKET_ID:  0xEF_csrss.exe_BUGCHECK_CRITICAL_PROCESS_d9dd1080_nt!PspCatchCriticalBreak

PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  0xEF_csrss.exe_BUGCHECK_CRITICAL_PROCESS_d9dd1080_nt!PspCatchCriticalBreak

TARGET_TIME:  2020-04-16T01:24:35.000Z

OSBUILD:  18362

OSSERVICEPACK:  657

SERVICEPACK_NUMBER: 0

OS_REVISION: 0

SUITE_MASK:  784

PRODUCT_TYPE:  1

OSPLATFORM_TYPE:  x64

OSNAME:  Windows 10

OSEDITION:  Windows 10 WinNt TerminalServer SingleUserTS Personal

OS_LOCALE:  

USER_LCID:  0

OSBUILD_TIMESTAMP:  2005-04-22 20:40:32

BUILDDATESTAMP_STR:  190318-1202

BUILDLAB_STR:  19h1_release

BUILDOSVER_STR:  10.0.18362.1.amd64fre.19h1_release.190318-1202

ANALYSIS_SESSION_ELAPSED_TIME:  4112

ANALYSIS_SOURCE:  KM

FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  km:0xef_csrss.exe_bugcheck_critical_process_d9dd1080_nt!pspcatchcriticalbreak

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {32a78def-91b8-2dc0-1e0c-9c73289688bd}

Followup:     MachineOwner
---------
```

From everything I have found online, it looks like the process `csrss.exe` died as a result of something `ntkrnlmp.exe` did. What can I do to fix this?

UPDATE: Happened again. Seems to be happening when the PC sits idle for 10 minutes or more. I have Rainmeter desktop gadgets installed, so I noticed that the hard drive indicated went from 813 GB free to 0 GB free.  When I went to check it out in the file explorer, the PC froze and BSOD’ed. Looks like svchost.exe went down this time.

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

CRITICAL_PROCESS_DIED (ef)
        A critical system process died
Arguments:
Arg1: ffff8e05150c5240, Process object or thread object
Arg2: 0000000000000000, If this is 0, a process died. If this is 1, a thread died.
Arg3: 0000000000000000
Arg4: 0000000000000000

Debugging Details:
------------------

ETW minidump data unavailable

KEY_VALUES_STRING: 1


PROCESSES_ANALYSIS: 1

SERVICE_ANALYSIS: 1

STACKHASH_ANALYSIS: 1

TIMELINE_ANALYSIS: 1


DUMP_CLASS: 1

DUMP_QUALIFIER: 400

BUILD_VERSION_STRING:  18362.1.amd64fre.19h1_release.190318-1202

DUMP_TYPE:  2

BUGCHECK_P1: ffff8e05150c5240

BUGCHECK_P2: 0

BUGCHECK_P3: 0

BUGCHECK_P4: 0

PROCESS_NAME:  svchost.exe

CRITICAL_PROCESS:  svchost.exe

EXCEPTION_RECORD:  ffffeff7fbfdf000 -- (.exr 0xffffeff7fbfdf000)
ExceptionAddress: 0000000000000000
   ExceptionCode: 19732867
  ExceptionFlags: 8a000001
NumberParameters: 0

EXCEPTION_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0x19732867 - <Unable to get error code text>

ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0x19732867 - <Unable to get error code text>

CPU_COUNT: 4

CPU_MHZ: db0

CPU_VENDOR:  GenuineIntel

CPU_FAMILY: 6

CPU_MODEL: 9e

CPU_STEPPING: 9

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN8_DRIVER_FAULT

BUGCHECK_STR:  0xEF

CURRENT_IRQL:  0

EXCEPTION_CODE_STR:  19732867

ANALYSIS_SESSION_HOST:  DESKTOP-6L7K90U

ANALYSIS_SESSION_TIME:  04-16-2020 10:41:49.0562

ANALYSIS_VERSION: 10.0.18362.1 amd64fre

TRAP_FRAME:  ffff800000000000 -- (.trap 0xffff800000000000)
Unable to read trap frame at ffff8000`00000000

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from fffff80432ecb1e9 to fffff804327c1510

STACK_TEXT:  
ffff8302`ba1dae18 fffff804`32ecb1e9 : 00000000`000000ef ffff8e05`150c5240 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KeBugCheckEx
ffff8302`ba1dae20 fffff804`32dc7893 : ffff8e05`150c5240 fffff804`3269c769 ffff8e05`150c5240 fffff804`3269c8c0 : nt!PspCatchCriticalBreak+0x115
ffff8302`ba1daec0 fffff804`32c3a190 : ffff8e05`00000000 00000000`00000000 ffff8e05`150c5240 ffff8e05`150c5240 : nt!PspTerminateAllThreads+0x175cbf
ffff8302`ba1daf30 fffff804`32c39f79 : ffffffff`ffffffff ffff8302`ba1db060 ffff8e05`150c5240 00000000`00000000 : nt!PspTerminateProcess+0xe0
ffff8302`ba1daf70 fffff804`327d2e15 : 00007ffa`00000418 ffff8e05`15b42080 ffff8e05`150c5240 ffff8302`ba1db1b0 : nt!NtTerminateProcess+0xa9
ffff8302`ba1dafe0 fffff804`327c5350 : fffff804`3282ff1e ffff8302`ba1dba58 ffff8302`ba1dba58 ffff8302`ba1db1b0 : nt!KiSystemServiceCopyEnd+0x25
ffff8302`ba1db178 fffff804`3282ff1e : ffff8302`ba1dba58 ffff8302`ba1dba58 ffff8302`ba1db1b0 00007ffa`1335ed61 : nt!KiServiceLinkage
ffff8302`ba1db180 fffff804`327d351d : ffffeff7`fbfdf000 ffff8302`ba1dbb00 ffff8000`00000000 0000007b`46a00f70 : nt!KiDispatchException+0x168bde
ffff8302`ba1db920 fffff804`327cf705 : 0000007b`46a0a170 ffff8302`ba1dbb80 00000000`00000000 ffff8302`ba1dbb80 : nt!KiExceptionDispatch+0x11d
ffff8302`ba1dbb00 00007ffa`14b8a0ae : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiPageFault+0x445
0000007b`46a00ef0 00000000`00000000 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : 0x00007ffa`14b8a0ae


THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD_FUNC:  f6b0f7fafbd5253fc3d42ad0a11af14fddabdcf0

THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD_FUNC_OFFSET:  be9170f6d614d257ce9be03cb2a996eeebc32fc4

THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD:  bc100a5647b828107ac4e18055e00abcbe1ec406

FOLLOWUP_IP: 
nt!PspCatchCriticalBreak+115
fffff804`32ecb1e9 cc              int     3

FAULT_INSTR_CODE:  ed8440cc

SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  1

SYMBOL_NAME:  nt!PspCatchCriticalBreak+115

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: nt

IMAGE_NAME:  ntkrnlmp.exe

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  4269a790

IMAGE_VERSION:  10.0.18362.657

STACK_COMMAND:  .thread ; .cxr ; kb

BUCKET_ID_FUNC_OFFSET:  115

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  0xEF_svchost.exe_BUGCHECK_CRITICAL_PROCESS_15b42080_nt!PspCatchCriticalBreak

BUCKET_ID:  0xEF_svchost.exe_BUGCHECK_CRITICAL_PROCESS_15b42080_nt!PspCatchCriticalBreak

PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  0xEF_svchost.exe_BUGCHECK_CRITICAL_PROCESS_15b42080_nt!PspCatchCriticalBreak

TARGET_TIME:  2020-04-16T15:35:59.000Z

OSBUILD:  18362

OSSERVICEPACK:  657

SERVICEPACK_NUMBER: 0

OS_REVISION: 0

SUITE_MASK:  784

PRODUCT_TYPE:  1

OSPLATFORM_TYPE:  x64

OSNAME:  Windows 10

OSEDITION:  Windows 10 WinNt TerminalServer SingleUserTS Personal

OS_LOCALE:  

USER_LCID:  0

OSBUILD_TIMESTAMP:  2005-04-22 20:40:32

BUILDDATESTAMP_STR:  190318-1202

BUILDLAB_STR:  19h1_release

BUILDOSVER_STR:  10.0.18362.1.amd64fre.19h1_release.190318-1202

ANALYSIS_SESSION_ELAPSED_TIME:  3fa4

ANALYSIS_SOURCE:  KM

FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  km:0xef_svchost.exe_bugcheck_critical_process_15b42080_nt!pspcatchcriticalbreak

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {c9157346-b9f8-fb7b-ce91-f559e80f2384}

Followup:     MachineOwner
---------
```

UPDATE: I contacted Microsoft Advisors. I was advised to disable fast startup. I found out through googling that fast startup holds the PC in a semi-hibernated state during shutdown. This makes sense as to why processes my be dying.

Comment: Can you update the computer BIOS using the bootable DVD or USB Key from the manufacturer?

Comment: @John I will definitely try. I do have the disk, but it is currently 9pm here and I am going to bed. This is first up for tomorrow. Thank you for throwing that in!

Comment: Please post the solution as an answer. Self-answering is okay. You'll be able to mark the question as solved.

Comment: @gronostaj alright

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wound up replacing the hard drive after a long, drawn out debacle with the manufacturer's RMA service.